# Why it is giving permission denied while running a shell script?

Tags: php, shell

After executing

```
frama-c -pdg -dot-pdg graph -pdg-print test.c
```

in a shell_script through php file. I am getting output as permission denied for graph.main.dot while directly executing the above command I am getting correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you run it, you are running it from your user account, and when PHP runs it, it is running it from the webserver account.

You have permission to access `graph.main.dot` but the web server does not.

You can alter the permissions using the `chmod` and `chgrp` commands.

Comment: What makes you think OP is running something described as _in a shell\_script through php file_ as the webserver user?

Comment: please specify how i can do it ?

Comment: @kojiro — That's a good point. It was an assumption since most people running things through PHP are doing so through a web server. I don't think it is an unreasonable one though since the OP hasn't said otherwise and its really rare to write a command line PHP wrapper around a bash script around a binary executable.

Comment: @user3449430 — I can't tell you precisely what commands you need to run because I don't know what the current permissions and ownership on the files are. You'll need to examine them (with `ls -l`) to determine what needs to be changed. If you haven't got a basic understanding on unix file system permissions, then I recommend you read [a primer on those first](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml).